# Django RestFrame work to update the fied

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My serializer fun is

```
class change_pwdform(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user.set_password(validated_data.get('new_password', new_password))
        user.save()
        return instance
    old_password = serializers.CharField(   style={'input_type': 'password'})
    new_password = serializers.CharField(   style={'input_type': 'password'})
    class  Meta:    
        fields = ( 'pty_email','old_password','new_password',)
        model = registration
```

in my model i have only the filed called

```
password field in model
```

my view function to change password is,

```
class Change_Password(mixins.ListModelMixin,
              mixins.CreateModelMixin,
              generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = change_pwdform
    def post(self, request, format=None):
            email = request.data['pty_email']
            pwd = request.data['old_password']
            user = registration.objects.filter(pty_email=email, pty_password=pwd)           
            if user:                        
                    user = registration.objects.get(pty_email=email)
                    request['password'] = request.data['new_password']
                    print request.data //says quickdict of email , password , new_password, and old_password
                    serializer = change_pwdform(object, data=request.DATA, partial=True)
                    if serializer.is_valid():
                        serializer.save()
                        data = { "result":"success"}
                        return Response(data)
            error ={"Invalid"}                                              
            return Response(error, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This request return a dict  ack: success  but the password is not yet changed.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wright an update function in your serializers like this.Following

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        user.set_password(validated_data.get('new_password', new_password))
        user.save()
        return instance
```

Here user is the user object and in your views.py you have to pass the model object like this

```
change_pwdform = change_pwdform(object, data=request.DATA, partial=True)
```

This worked for me and **you can also refer** "http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update"

Comment: Please see my edit as you said, but it says user name is not defined in    user.set_password(validated_data.get('new_password', new_password))